# VBA Subscript Out of Range when allocating value to first and second dimension of Dynamic Multidimensional Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I am creating a Dynamic Multidimensional Array that has 3 dimensions.  When I try to allocate a value to the first and second dimension I get the error `Subscript Out of Range`.

My code:

```vb
Dim wb as Workbook, filNme  as String, y As Integer, i As Long, rng As Long
Dim hArr() As Variant, dimen1 As Long, dimen2 As Long, dimen3 As Long
Dim tArr() As Variant, dim1 As Long, dim2 As Long, dim3 As Long, dim4 As Long
i = 0
filNme = "Test1"
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\" & filNme & ".xlsx")
With wb    
    For y = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
        If .Worksheets(y).Range("R5").Value = 1 Then
            i = .Worksheets(y).Range("B88").End(xlUp).Row
            rng = .Worksheets(y).Range("B48:B" & i).Count - 1
            ReDim hArr(0, 0, 0 To rng)
            hArr(0) = CStr(.Worksheets(y).Range("B7").Value) 'Gives Subscript Out of Range error
            hArr(0, 0) = .Worksheets(y).Range("B8").Value 'Gives Subscript Out of Range error
            For dimen1 = LBound(hArr, 1) To UBound(hArr, 1)
                For dimen2 = LBound(hArr, 2) To UBound(hArr, 2)
                    For dimen3 = LBound(hArr, 3) To UBound(hArr, 3)
                        hArr(dimen1, dimen2, dimen3) = .Worksheets(y).Range("B" & 48 + dimen3).Value
                    Next dimen3
                Next dimen2
            Next dimen1
        End If
    Next y
End With
```

Data:
Range("B7") : String or Integer
Range("B8") : Double
Range("B48:B" & i) : Dynamic String Range
None of the other answers gave me clarity.  Can someone please give me an idea why I get the error?

Comment: You have dimensioned an array of variants in 3 dimensions. The two lines that give you errors are because you attempt to assign a value to an element of the array without specifying three indexes. You MUST ALWAYS use the same number of indexes into the array as the array has dimensions. No exceptions, ever. VBA has no way to know which element you are attempting to refer to otherwise.

Comment: An array in 3 dimensions is conceptually a cube. But what you have done by declaring the first and second dimensions both of size zero is effectively made a difficult-to-work-with vector. Your array has only `rng` elements and they can only be accessed by providing the three indexes. For example, the first element is `hArr(0, 0, 0)`. The second element is `hArr(0, 0, 1)`. The third element is `hArr(0, 0, 2)`. Etc.

Comment: In your scheme of declaring the first and second dimensions to be of size zero, you have effectively wasted the first two dimensions. You have a 1d array that now requires three indexes.

Comment: @ExcelHero You are  correct.  Thank you! If you make your comment the answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have dimensioned an array of variants in 3 dimensions.

The two lines that give you errors are because you attempt to assign a value to an element of the array without specifying three indexes.

You MUST ALWAYS use the same number of indexes into the array as the array has dimensions. No exceptions, ever. VBA has no way to know which element you are attempting to refer to otherwise.

An array in 3 dimensions is conceptually a cube. But what you have done by declaring the first and second dimensions both of size zero is effectively made a difficult-to-work-with vector.

Your array has only `rng` elements and those elements can only be accessed by providing all three indexes. For example, the first element is `hArr(0, 0, 0)`. The second element is `hArr(0, 0, 1)`. The third element is `hArr(0, 0, 2)`. Etc.

In your scheme of declaring the first and second dimensions to be of size zero, you have effectively wasted the first two dimensions. You have a 1d array that now requires three indexes to refer to each element.

---

Update

Consider the following for a jagged array structure.

```
Dim t

Redim t(1 to 3)

t(1) = "Unique Value 1"
t(2) = "Unique Value 2"
t(3) = Array(1, 2, 3, "Some other value")
```

Note that here I assigned a 1d array to `t(3)` but it could have been a 2d array, or an array of any rank.

To get the values out, you do it like this...

```
Debug.Print t(1)
Debug.Print t(2)
Debug.Print t(3)(0)
Debug.Print t(3)(1)
Debug.Print t(3)(2)
Debug.Print t(3)(3)
```

Every element in a variant array can potentially hold a separate array. And each element in those separate arrays could potentially hold new arrays. And on and on. So extremely complex data structures are possible and permissible with this approach.

Comment: Thanks again. Your input is much appreciated. I was aiming to create a tree like structure where the first dimension and the 2nd dimension each has a unique value and the third has the dynamic values. I will make the 1st and 2nd dimensions larger and see what happens.

Comment: A variant array can have elements that are themselves arrays. You can have a "jagged" array this way. That would be ideal for a tree.

Comment: I will update my answer to show you how to make the jagged array.

Comment: Brevity is the soul of wit.  Thank you.